# group by values based on an operator condition - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, pivot

I have a table that has values split whether a customer has clicked, or not clicked on said fictional website. And I want to compare the distribution of those who have/haven't, table as below:

```
gender  country clicks
male    US  1
male    US  0
male    US  3
male    US  2
female  US  1
female  US  0
female  US  0
```

The output should like:

```
gender  country notclicked clicked
female  US      2          1
male    US      1          3
```

but the only way I can figure out doing this is through two separate queries and adding them together, *manually*:

```
select gender, country, count(clicks) as not_clicked from performance
where clicks = 0
group by gender, country;

select gender, country, count(clicks) as clicked from performance
where clicks >= 1
group by gender, country;
```

How do I make this query smarter and run in one go?

Fiddle below for table schema and queries

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ffa22/5)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data and results do not really align to your description of the problem. Based on your existing queries, I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select
    gender,
    country,
    count(*) filter(where clicks = 0) not_clicked,
    count(*) filter(where clicks > 0) clicked
from performance
group by gender, country
```

Comment: Yeah noticed I mixed the genders around in copying the table, thanks for the pick up, but this works really well. Knew it would be simple

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select gender, country, sum(1 - clicks) as not_clicked, sum(clicks) as clicked
from performance
where clicks = 0
group by gender, country;
```

It looks like `clicks` is a number that takes on `0` or `1` values.

More generally, I would recommend `filter`:

```
select gender, country, 
       count(*) filter (where clicked = 0) as not_clicked,
       count(*) filter where click = 1) as clicked
from performance
where clicks = 0
group by gender, country;
```